# How to implement confidence intervalls into a Weibull-plot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I'm working on the plotting of a strength-dataset in a `ProbabilityScalePlot` and want to have a nicer version of how to automatically implement the confidence intervalls (90% or 95%) into the plot.
Until now i calculate four `HalfLine` lines and plot it into the `ProbabilityScalePlot` like in the shortened code segment (the data is not fulfilling the confidence intervalls given due to a correction factor used for encryption):

```
halflines={HalfLine[{6.1, 0}, {-1, -14.1}], 
 HalfLine[{6.1, 0}, {1, 22.96}], 
 HalfLine[{6.1, 0}, {1, 14.1}], 
 HalfLine[{6.1, 0}, {-1, -22.96}]}

dataset={422.918, 488.943, 436.838, 420.08, 481.187, 430.53, 433.959, 414.308, 468.762, 470.08, 459.893, 428.151, 423.193, 421.472, 484.492, 463.508, 428.949, 497.333, 470.477, 402.887, 471.617, 433.492, 415.18, 420.383, 474.359, 447.246, 445.556, 480.03, 459.678, 448.732} 

ProbabilityScalePlot[dataset, "Weibull", 
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {halflines}]
```

Is there anything possible to implement it within a built-in function, or do you have any idea?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does "the data is not fulfilling the confidence intervalls given due to a correction factor used for encryption" mean?

Comment: that the whole data is not provided and so the confidence levels are not fitting perfectly :)

Comment: I wonder if there is a language issue because otherwise your last comment sounds like you have the ability to produce confidence intervals in *Mathematica* with a "home-grown" set of code and are just interested in finding out if there's something built-in.